# How to convert string to date formar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below code which converts **Date** into **int64**.

```
import datetime as dt
Date = pd.to_datetime(['29-05-2017'])
Date = Date.map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
Date
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Int64Index([736478], dtype='int64')
```

As you can see from the above output as it has been changed to **736478** and now I'm looking for code where it converts the **int64** value to **date** it means from **736478** to **29-05-2017**

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: Use `Date = pd.Index([736478,736478])
print (Date.map(pd.Timestamp.fromordinal))`

Comment: Got that. Thanks for your help.!!